# Commenting out a function using sed or regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a large piece of C code and in the middle is a function that i want to comment out using macros

```
...
...
```

xyzFunction (){
    ...
    ..

```
}
...
```

Should become

```
#ifndef COMMENT_OUT
```

xyzFunction (){
    ...
    ..
    .
    }
    #endif
    ..

I can add the `#ifndef` COMMENT OUT using the following sed command
`sed '/xyzFunction/ i #ifndef COMMENT_OUT' file1.c > opt;mv opt file1.c`

But how do i find the matching curly braces that close this function so that i can put an #endif after it?

Comment: **matching curly braces** using sed? Good luck

Comment: *awk* might be better tool, if you don't want to go to the "big" scripting languages... Also you have to make some assumptions about code formatting, if you want to do this without full C parser.

Comment: Could you give me an awk command for the same?

Comment: Parsing C is hard. Counting curlies doesn't work, consider `void foo() { char c = '}'; }`. (And if you've fixed your hack for that, consider any code that has `#define END }` or such other "niceties".) If you're serious about this use an exiting parser (I believe clang's LibTooling can be used for this sort of thing.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this `sed` command

```
sed  '/xyzFunction (){/s/.*/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n&/;/}/s/.*/&\n#endif/'
```

or

```
sed '/runTaskCode(.*)/s/.*/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n&/;/}/s/.*/&\n#endif/'
```

**Explanation :**

First match the function name `/runTaskCode(.*)/` ,If function name has  matched then put your string in previous line like `s/.*/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n&/` .Then match the closing curly brace ,if matched then put your string after matched line like `/}/s/.*/&\n#endif/`

Comment: The function is called void runTaskCode(void* unused). I tried the command sed  '/runTaskCode{/s/.*/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n&/;/}/s/.*/&\n#endif/' run.c | less Didn't work

Comment: Remove curly braces , like `sed '/runTaskCode(.*)/s/.*/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n&/;/}/s/.*/&\n#endif/' run.c `

Comment: Cool! that worked. Thanks. Could you explain the command a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
sed 's/^\(xyzFunction (){\)$/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n\1/; s/}$/}\n#endif/' file name
```

Or try this,

```
sed 's/\(.*(.*){\)/#ifndef COMMENT_OUT\n\1/; s/}$/}\n#endif/' file name
```

Comment: No luck. Just for info, the function doesn't take a void input. Here's the definition. Tried modifying the regex suitably. no luck. void runTaskCode(void *unused)